# What Partner org it is recommended to perfom testing?

Tags: org, partner, unit-test

What Partner org(EE or GE or both) it is recommended to perfom QA/testing?

Comment: Perform testing for what, an app, a production SFDC instance? What kind of testing? Your question needs to be a bit more specific. For example: "I'm building a managed package app and I'd like to QA my app for end user testing. What's the best environment for this type of QA?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Salesforce ISV Force** guide has a [topic](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_testing_editions.htm) on testing and states this...

> As a Force.com ISV Partner, you are entitled to a variety of environments for developing, testing, and demoing your Force.com app. In general, you'll want to test your app in every edition that you want to support.

Its a pretty general statement, but the key part is basically the editions your supporting. In practice, since there is obviously cost related to doing the testing, unless you've invested in automation. You have to take a measured assessment on exactly what org types you test in and what functionality depth you test at.

A factor is clearly what **features of the platform your using**, in some cases certain **explicit** platform feature usage will designate the package only installable in the required edition anyway. However their are ways your developers can **dynamically** respond to features availability or not. This topic [Architectural Considerations for Group and Professional Editions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_packages_for_pe_ge.htm) is well worth a read which talks about architecting for different editions, something to cross check discuss with your developers. Also see [Features Available in Group and Professional Editions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_package_features_pe_ge.htm).

> If you plan to sell your app to existing Salesforce customers, it’s important to understand the differences between these editions because they will affect the design of your app. It’s convenient to think about them in clusters, GE/PE and EE/UE/PXE, as the editions in each cluster have similar functionality. For example, you might only want to support EE/UE/PXE if your app requires certain objects and features that aren't available in GE/PE. Also, instead of a single solution that supports all editions, you can have a tiered offering. This would consist of a basic solution for GE/PE and an advanced one for EE/UE/PXE customers that takes advantage of the additional features.

Having a tiered approach (as described in more detail in the docs) can help, as you would have packages adding functionality for each org type. By reviewing this you should be able to come up with a targeted set of smoke/regression tests to try out certain potentially vulnerable features of your app in appropriate org types. Which is backed by a suite of sold Apex tests and/or automated tests you run in your most common user org type.